# Java, fake 3D effect

Tags: java, bufferedimage, affinetransform

How to achieve effect like on the pic below using `AffineTransform` or something on `AffineTransform`? Or any other effect/transform in Java that I can use on `BufferedImage` ?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at my edited answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The effect you want to achieve is called **Skewing** 
Take a look at the **Skew** section @ http://www.javaxt.com/javaxt-core/javaxt.io.Image/

First of all download the javaxt api.
The `Image` class has a public constructor which accepts `BufferedImage` as an argument , see below

```
   javaxt.io.Image image = new javaxt.io.Image(java.awt.image.BufferedImage bufferedImage);
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();
    image.setCorners(20, 70,              //UL
                     width-70, 0,         //UR
                     width+20, height-50, //LR
                     50, height);         //LL
```

*setCorners is sed to skew an image by updating the corner coordinates. Coordinates are supplied in clockwise order starting from the upper left corner.*

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can use it with BufferedImage?

Comment: Thanks it works, but I took only private class "Skew" from javaxt.io.Image class. So only what I was needed.